# How to find out if hibernation is available for a Windows user (with C++)

Tags: c++, winapi, power-state

I know that one can call the following API to hibernate the system:

`SetSuspendState(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE);`

But is there any way to find out if "real" hibernation is available for the current Windows user?

Here's what I mean:

1. If an admin calls:

   ```
   powercfg.exe /hibernate off
   ```

   the API above will put system into a Sleep mode. So how do you know (from a C++ program) that this will happen instead of hibernation?
2. I'm not sure if there's a group policy that can prohibit a user from hibernating a computer connected to an Active Directory?

> **Edit** I am aware of the (dated) `IsPwrHibernateAllowed` API. I find that it doesn't work: it still returns the same result even if `powercfg.exe /hibernate off` was called. Am I doing something wrong there? Can someone explain why `IsPwrHibernateAllowed` doesn't work for me?

Comment: Google "IsPwrHibernateAllowed"

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373163(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Hans Passant IsPwrHibernateAllowed is an outdated API, but it still returns the same result even if powercfg.exe /hibernate off was called. I also scoured all over those Power Management Functions with any luck ((

Comment: @ahmd0: That kind of information should obviously have been in the question! Prevent people from wasting time coming up with the obvious answers that you already tried?

Comment: Good addition. So, can you answer your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at `SYSTEM_POWER_CAPABILITIES` structure that can be obtained with [CallNtPowerInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372675%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Specifically, look at `HiberFilePresent` field.

Comment: Thanks. It looks promising. Although I still can't find a parameter to use to determine what I need?

Comment: I think I got it. Thanks for the clue: SYSTEM_POWER_CAPABILITIES:HiberFilePresent

Comment: @ahmd0: Yep, that's what I was looking at when decided to post an answer. Sorry I didn't mention it explicitly.